# getPersistedString has protected access

Tags: java, android

i just changed my code from

> DialogPreference

to

> PreferenceDialogFragmentCompat

but i got an error here

```
getPreference().getPersistedString("wwww");
```

the error said

> getPersistedString(java.lang.String)' has protected access in
>   'android.support.v7.preference.Preference

so what is the alternative for getPersistedString in v7 preference

Comment: Did you find the correct way?

Comment: @LppEdd iam trying now i will try your answer

Comment: Did it work in the end?

Comment: @LppEdd yes thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an Android developer, but by looking at the source, you can use

```
public Set<String> getPersistedStringSet(Set<String> defaultReturnValue);
```

this way

```
final Set<String> values = getPreference().getPersistedStringSet(defaultValues);
```

Than you could loop the `Set` and find the appropriate value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Preference preference = getPreference();
String persistedString = preference.getSharedPreferences().
                           getString(preference.getKey(), "defaultString");
```